# Xamarin SensorType.Orientation is deprecated?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-sensors

I have seen that in Java Android the

```
Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION
```

is deprecated from the API Level 20. ([link here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html))

In Xamarin Android there is the ([link here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Hardware.SensorType.Orientation/))

```
SensorType.Orientation
```

The question is: this sensor type is the same deprecated in Android - Java or is a different type I can use without any problem?

Thank you,

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is: this sensor type is the same deprecated in Android - Java or is a different type I can use without any problem?

Yes, this sensor type is the same deprecated in Android. For API Level 20 or later, please use [SensorManager.GetOrientation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Hardware.SensorManager.GetOrientation/p/System.Single[]/System.Single[]/).